# SetCursor C++ Not Working

Tags: c++, winapi, set, cursor

I read Microsoft's documentation and I tried myself but it's not working. Cursor doesn't change

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment (lib, “User32.lib”)
#include <Winuser.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    HCURSOR cur = LoadCursorFromFile("cursor.cur");
    SetCursor(cur);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

"cur" is not null by the way.
Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Displaying_a_Cursor

Comment: Are you sure you can compile this line? `#pragma comment (lib, “User32.lib”)` Because you can't use `“` and `”` for string literals AFAIK.

Comment: `SetCursor` is for `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` only. Your code targets `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`, and `SetCursor` has no effect.

Comment: `SetCursor` only changes the cursor "momentarily", in response to a `WM_SETCURSOR` message. Maybe you're looking for `SetSystemCursor` instead?